# Git rebase squash producing different results to plain rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, squash, git-squash

When I perform a `git rebase -i -X theirs` and squash all commits except the first, some of the resulting files are different to the most recent version of the file in the branch that I'm rebasing, whereas if I do a plain `git rebase -X theirs` the files are as I expect them to be.

Can somebody explain to me why this is?

Comment: Do the commits you are rebasing contain merge commits?

Comment: @padawin No merge commits.

Comment: in the interactive mode, when you mark your commits as being squashed, do you see all your commits, or from here some are missing already?

Comment: @padawin There are a lot of commits and the branch has had a lot of work over a long period of time but they do seem to all be there.

Comment: Not knowing the repository, I'd try narrowing down the issue, squash some commits, check the result, until you find a subset of commits which make it behave like that. Also, do you have a way to create a shareable example reproducing the issue?

Comment: Also what is the result of: `git rebase <parentbranch>` and `git rebase -i <parentbranch>` (basically without the `-X`)?